# Visual studio 2013 installation issue with NugetVS

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to install visual studio 2013 in the brand new machine with windows 8.1 . My setup failes with the following error

```
[1D84:1D88][2014-11-30T09:51:02]i301: Applying execute package: nugetvs2013, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{AFF89951-EFF1-3543-92CE-BE535855A3A7}v2.8.50926.663\packages\WPT\NuGetVS2013.msi, arguments: ' ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT="1" MSIFASTINSTALL="7"'
[1DA8:1DAC][2014-11-30T09:51:06]i000: MUX:  ExecuteError: Package (nugetvs2013) failed: Error Message Id: 1722 ErrorMessage: There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.  
[1D84:1D88][2014-11-30T09:51:06]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to install MSI package.
[1D84:1D88][2014-11-30T09:51:06]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
[1DA8:1DAC][2014-11-30T09:51:06]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to configure per-machine MSI package.
```

Just to not I am the admin of the machine . even though vs setup shows it a warning when trying to open I am getting the following exception

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I could resolve the same problem for me by,

1. deinstalling nugetvs from Visual Studio -> Tools -> Extensions
   and Updates
2. installing another version of nugetvs from
   https://nuget.codeplex.com/

Comment: Could you be more specific on which version of nugetvs fixed the issue.